# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win10toast' ; bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have already installed both of them using the pip command and it shows it is installed and yet is not working. I have also updated the version of pip still it shows the command to update the pip.

```
    C:\Users\DELL>pip install win10toast
    Requirement already satisfied: win10toast in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (0.9)
    Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from win10toast) (40.8.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from win10toast) (223)
    Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from pypiwin32->win10toast) (225)
    You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.2.3 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

    C:\Users\DELL>cd C:\Users\DELL\desktop

    C:\Users\DELL\Desktop>python test.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
        from win10toast import ToastNotifier
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win10toast'
```

```
C:\Users\DELL\Desktop>pip install lxml
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (4.4.1)
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\DELL\Desktop>pip3 install lxml
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (4.4.1)
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\DELL\Desktop>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 196, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

Comment: What is your default python version?

Comment: try to import using ```python shell``` if it works well, then it will work in script. If not then check the python version as well as pip version whil installing.

Comment: python version is 3.7 and pip as reflected in code snippet is 19.0.3

Comment: I even tried pip list command and both of the modules are visible in it and it is not even recognized in IDLE and sublime Text 3

Comment: could you check what is returned when you run `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` in your `cmd`?

Comment: I installed anaconda to overcome it, this is now its printing : ` ['', `'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python37.zip', `'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib', `'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-`packages', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', `'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', `'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']      The lxml problem is solved but still don't know what to do about win10 toast

Comment: Python was originally in this folder :C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7

Comment: Can you look further in it? @FlyingTeller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down what is happening:

1. Your `pip install lxml` command resulted in an already satisfied error in the folder `"...python\python37\lib\site-packages..."`
2. `pip3 install lxml` resulted in an already satisfied error in the folder `"...python\python37\lib\site-packages..."`

So both your `pip` and `pip3` were pointing to the `python` distribution installed in 
`"...python\python37`, but when you execute your script, `bs4` is imported from `"...Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages..."` (note that **Python37-32** is different from the paths `pip` pointed to). This leads me to believe that you somehow have two different `python` installations side by side and that `pip` and `python` point to different ones, which creates a mess.

In the comments you say that you have installed `anaconda`, which of course is now a third `python` distribution. In order to clear this up, I would recommend to

1. Uninstall the `python` installations you had before, afterwards, make sure that both the `"...Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages..."` and `"...python\python37\lib\site-packages..."` are gone/emptied
2. Make sure that all commands like `python` `pip` are now all pointing to your `anaconda` installation
3. Create and activate a virutal environment for your project (if desired)
4. Install `bs4`: `conda install -c anaconda beautifulsoup4` and `win10toast`:`pip install win10toast`

Now all imports should be working fine

Comment: you saved me so much time, that was exactly the issue,