# Pip installing "win10toast" on vscode, module wont show up?

Tags: python

When putting

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
toaster = ToastNotifier()
toaster.show_toast("Sample Notification","Python is awesome!!!")
```

the error keep's saying "No module named 'win10toast'
I have downloaded it on my computer and everything should work, I also tried in shell and it said the same thing.

so I decided to see if it was installed and the command prompt still says it is. I am very confused.

Comment: Did you initialize your pipenv?

Comment: What output do you see when you check at the command prompt? What command do you run at the command prompt to check this?

Comment: @SeanLawton  How do I do that? And where?

Comment: @ShaneBishop either pip install win10toast or install win10toast

Comment: @Synthx You say "I decided to see if it was installed and the command prompt still says it is". What command did you run to check that "it was installed"? Please provide that command and the full output from running that command.

Comment: use the command "pipenv shell" to initialize your pipenv then cd to the working directory

Comment: @ShaneBishop "pip install win10toast" output: Requirement already satisfied: win10toast in  ((##"my file"))

Comment: @SeanLawton tried it in both vscode and command prompt (terminal's) and both outputs were "'pipenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: 1. What operating system are you using? 2. Are you sure your vscode project's python interpreter matches the python interpreter for your command prompt? See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter) for details. 3. What do you see when you run "python --version" and "python -m pip list" (please put the output for these commands in your question, not in a comment).

Comment: @ShaneBishop I am using windows 10. 2. yes   3. Python 3.9.1,                       pypiwin32  223
pywin32    300
win10toast 0.9
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the

Comment: @SeanLawton   it seems this guys: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58267660/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-win10toast-bs4-featurenotfound-couldn has the exact same output as me... But I am not using andaconda

Comment: Holy #### everyone, I deleted all the older versions of my python and it worked! thanks to every that has helped me along the way. THANK YOU GUYS SO MUCH! @ShaneBishop

Answer (score -1):

I deleted all prior versions of my python (3.6-3.8) and kept my newest one.

Comment: Although this solution may have worked in your case, it is not the proper solution. This will not work for people who need to have multiple versions of python 3.x installed at the same time.